# Why is spring.profiles.active set in test class not available in environment property of the actual class under test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

Will I be able access enviorment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") in the class that I am trying to test by setting @ActiveProfiles on Test class,

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = TradeController.class)
    @ActiveProfiles("test)
    class TradeControllerTest{
       @Autowired
       private MockMvc mockMvc;
       
    
        @MockBean
        private TradeServiceImpl tradeServiceImpl;
    
        @Mock
        private ConfigurableEnvironment enviroment;
    
        @Before
        public void setup(){
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
       @Test
        public void test() throws Exception{
          Mockito.doNothing().when(tradeServiceImpl).getAllTrades(any());
          RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilder.get(new 
              URI("/getTrades")).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
          MvcResult  result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn(); // calling the 
                                       actual class under test
          assertEquals(result.getResponse().getStatus(), 400);
        }
}
```

Below is the class, where I am reading spring.profiles.active. It is however, coming null

```
@RestController
public class TradeController{

  @Autowired
  private TradeServiceImpl tradeServiceImpl; 
 
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @GetMapping("/getTrade")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getTrade(@PathVariable final String 
    tradeId){
         String profile = environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the active profile with `environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")`, there is the specific [`Environment#getActiveProfiles`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--) method that returns the set of profiles explicitly made active for this environment. So if you autowired your `ApplicationContext` *ctx* in your class you can obtain the set of active profiles like below :

```
Environment env = ctx.getEnvironment();
String[] profiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
```